# Forward declaration for boost::intrusive_ptr class to reduce compile time

Tags: c++, boost, forward-declaration

I have class `A` which holds some data using `boost::intrusive_ptr`:

```
#include "Data.h"

class A {
    boost::intrusive_ptr<Data> data;
}
```

Class `Data` is a succesor of base class `RefCounted` for which functions `intrusive_ptr_release` and `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` are implemented as required.

I am going to reduce compile time, so I am trying to use forward declaration:

```
class Data;

class A {
    boost::intrusive_ptr<Data> data;
}
```

It does not compile saying

> 'intrusive_ptr_release': identifier not found

I tried to add declarations of needed functions:

```
class Data;

void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(RefCounted *);
void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounted *);

class A {
    boost::intrusive_ptr<Data> data;
}
```

Now it says

> 'void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounted *)': cannot convert argument 1
>   from 'Data *' to 'RefCounted *' pointed to are unrelated; conversion
>   requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

I understand meaning of compiler errors: it does not know that `RefCounted` is a superclass for `Data` because `Data` is an incomplete type. But, anyway, is there any way or trick possible here to avoid including of header `Data.h` to speed up compilation when dealing with boost intrusive pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one solution to your problem I know is to make sure there are no (implicitly) defined constructors or destructors for `A` in your header file. The minimal example would look like:

(header file)

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
class Data;

struct A {
    boost::intrusive_ptr<Data> data;
    A();
    ~A();
};

void foo() {
   A a;
}
```

Than, you'd have a .cpp file somewhere, which would define (could default) constructor and destructor for A, and include definition for class `Data`.

Comment: Awesome answer. Interesting (and a bit counterintuitive for me) that one have to sacrifice run-time performance (I mean to make ctor/dtor not-inlined) to make compilation fast.

Comment: @Nick that's always the case, though. By making stuff not-inlined, you sacrifice compile-time inlining and gain compilation speed. LTO might come to rescue, though.